# How to install VLC media player in CentOS6?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos-6

I am using the CentOS, version 6, GNU/Linux distribution. I am in need to install VLC media player, what command i need to use at the terminal? I have tried yum install *vlc*.

Answer (score 1):

Third-party repository RPMForge/RepoForge has a VLC package. Instructions to add this repository are here: http://repoforge.org/use/.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://pkgrepo.linuxtech.net/el6/release/linuxtech.repo
yum list *vlc*
yum -y install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

vlc doesn't exist in the main CentOS repositories. You'll have to either install from source or add a third-party (unofficial) repo that has packaged vlc into an RPM for you.

Here is a [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83637/how-can-i-install-latest-vlc-player-in-cent-os-6-4) to a duplication question on stackexchange with an answer that may work for you.